# How to redirect users to another site and allow only bots to index?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect all the users to current live site and allow bots to index the new one.
How can I achieve this?

Redirect to remote site if it is user browsing.

Allow bot to index the devloped site

Example:
domain.com is looked up, if this is a user browsing I send him tom anotherdomain.com
if it is a bot I let him continue browsing current site.

Comment: why would you want to do that?  That is a blackhat SEO technique and you will be penalised as spam.  Google et al aren't silly - they want to crawl what your users see.

Comment: The client asked me, Client wants to change to new site after it gets indexed

Comment: Better off just launching the new site, add Redirects from the Old to the New for Users & Spiders, and then using Google Webmaster Tools to request a crawl of the new site.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you would want to do this legitimately, but, as the question was asked...

```
# Determine if the User Agent is a Targetted Spider or Bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Start of the Spider User-Agent String" is_bot
# Add as many lines as are needed here...

# Set the 403 Forbidden location as the Real Visitor Site
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.real-visitors-go-here.com/

# Apply the Targetted Spider or Bot Check to Access
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from env=is_bot
</Limit>
```

Never done it myself, but that kind of makes sense.

Comment: Cool. I would still strongly recommend that you simply launch the new site, redirect everyone from the old to the new, and then request Google crawl the new site. There is no real benefit in having a site indexed by Google before letting people see it.

Comment: There is a real benefit for the competition :) as the client's website will be banned by all mayor search engines for blackhat SEO techniques.